# I want to display my labels "etc vegan, pasta...so on", by using map from firestore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display my labels "etc vegan, pasta...so on", by using map from firestore but I only find it possible to map out the first object [0]? I want to map out all the options not just one, how can I make this possible?

This is possible:

```
{restaurant.map((option, marker) => (
<p key={marker.id}><strong>{option.selectedOption[0].label}</strong></p>
))}
```

But when removing [0], it dosn't work to map out all objects.

[image: From my firestore]

Comment: Hi! You want to display an option's labels on a single row ?

Comment: can you show what is inside restaurant variable, selectedOption or something else.

Comment: Hi Martial, yes I want to display options labels on one single row.

Comment: Ok. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Array map function on **option.selectedOption** too

just like:

```
{restaurant.map((option, marker) => (
                <p key={marker.id}>

                    {option.selectedOption.map((optn, index) => (
                        <strong key={index}>
                            {optn.label + ', '}
                        </strong>
                    ))}
                </p>
            ))}
```

and show the label and value according to your requirement inside JSX

Answer (score 0):

You should do that instead:

```
{restaurant.map((option, marker) => (
    <p key={marker.id}>
        <strong>
            {option.selectedOption.reduce(labels, label, index => labels +=  `${index > 0 ? ', ' : ''}${label}`, '')}
        </strong>
    </p>
))}
```

The array function `reduce()` allow you to (as the name says) reduce and array into an single value.

More info [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)